# wordpress database hacked with theme

Tags: sql, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I had my 2 wordpress websites hacked last week.
When you are going on it you'll be redirect to another website (changing but usually it's a credit card spam thing related)
After restoring many times, and cleaning all the files, one of my website is fine but the other one still has a problem.
I tried many things, and I think it's related to the homepage theme + the DB. I explain:
its all good if I activate my theme(sydney) with a whole new DB, it's good with other themes too.
But if I want to use the original DB I have, everytime I insert one specific line into the wp_post I got the redirection. the row is to make the whole homepage working, I don't find what's strange in it but here's the row:

```
INSERT INTO `wp2_posts` VALUES
```

(4,1,'2017-08-08 17:26:22','2017-08-08 15:26:22','[siteorigin_widget class=\"Sydney_Services_Type_A\"][/siteorigin_widget][siteorigin_widget class=\"Sydney_Latest_News\"][/siteorigin_widget][siteorigin_widget class=\"WP_Widget_Custom_HTML\"][/siteorigin_widget][siteorigin_widget class=\"Sydney_Video_Widget\"][/siteorigin_widget][siteorigin_widget class=\"Sydney_Action\"][/siteorigin_widget][siteorigin_widget class=\"Sydney_Services_Type_A\"][/siteorigin_widget][siteorigin_widget class=\"WP_Widget_Custom_HTML\"][/siteorigin_widget][siteorigin_widget class=\"Sydney_Clients\"][/siteorigin_widget]','Homepage','','publish','closed','closed','','homepage','','','2018-07-22 19:26:01','2018-07-22 17:26:01','',0,'http://alessentiel.fr/?page_id=4',0,'page','',0)

It also seems to redirect when I try to personalize the theme directly on wordpress...

If anynone has any idea, please let me know because I can't find any other bug :((
Thanks

Comment: How did you clean your files?  You have to delete ALL files and redownload and install them (wordpress, themes, plugins etc.). Just save away the original uploads folder (and maybe some other plugin specific ones), check them thouroughly, especially for php files that are not supposed to be there.  
Since the error appears when you enter this line, there might be specific problem in siteorigin_widget shortcode.

Comment: Thanks Beatroot, I redownloaded and installed everything (theme and wordpress files) except the plugin because I thought it would screw the disposition I personalized... I just did now and it seems to work. Thanks a lot :)